# Java -- StringBuilder using String & not StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I'm using `StringBuilder`, instead of `String`, in my code in effort 
to make the code time-efficient during all that parsing & concatenation.

But when i look into its source, the `substring()` method of
`AbstractStringBuilder` and thus `StringBuilder` is returning a `String` and not a `StringBuilder`.

What would be the idea behind this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the name is **substring**, not **substringbuilder**.

Comment: You might be looking for `subSequence(int start, int end)`. (P.S., why do you insist on using **bold** instead of `code` formatting for code?)

Comment: @TedHopp Hopp nope, thats not the Q. that and substring are next to one another in the code.

Comment: @Kayaman what are you talking about. there hasn't been a "substringbuilder" in this text since the creation of Earth.

Comment: How would you expect to use a `StringBuilder` that was returned from `substring()`?

Comment: What is the question? Why it returns a String instead of a StringBuilder? Why would it return a StringBuilder? You can just make a new StringBuilder with the returned String.

Comment: I'm just going to say that trying to use `StringBuilder` as a replacement for `String` has so many potential pitfalls that this is really just the start of your troubles.

Answer (score 6):

The reason the `substring` method returns an immutable `String` is that once you get a part of the string inside your `StringBuilder`, it must make a copy. It cannot give you a mutable "live view" into the middle of `StringBuilder`'s content, because otherwise you would run into conflicts of which changes to apply to what string.

Since a copy is to be made anyway, it might as well be immutable: you can easily make it mutable if you wish by constructing a `StringBuilder` around it, with full understanding that it is detached from the mutable original.

Comment: Regarding the second para, that would require a double copy instead of a single copy, right?

Comment: In theory the mutable "live view" could work in much the same way that `subList` works for a list. Mutating the sublist writes through to the original list, and mutating a "`SubStringBuilder`" could mutate the backing `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @TedHopp That's certainly true, although that would require an introduction of a common interface, say, `MutableString`, and implementing it in the original `StringBuilder` and the (presumably hidden) `SubStringBuilder` -- the same way it's done in `subList`.

Comment: @TedHopp this would actually be a nightmare. Consider what happens if you append something to the "sub" StringBuilder. Should that be reflected in the original, too?

Comment: @Ingo - It works that way with `subList`. Sure, it's complicated, but why would it be a nightmare? The really interesting question is what would happen to the "sub" if the original were mutated within the range of the sub.

Comment: @Ingo `SubStringBuilder` could implement a copy on write. But you are right, it wouldn't be too intuitive.

Comment: @NPE Yes, this would require an additional copy. On the other hand, if you change `substring` to return `StringBuilder`, one would need to copy in order to make an immutable `String`. The only workable solution that I see would be adding a `substringBuilder` method.

Comment: @TedHopp We live in times where even the Java folks recognize that we need immutability and more functional code, and then such a intransparent monster, but apart from that, I am not discussing if it was technically possible, but rather desirable.

Comment: Having a locking strategy to make this live view possible would defeat the `StringBuilder`s purpose of non-sync operations in order to be fast. So maybe it would be better to create another object for this entire purpose and leave `StringBuilder` alone. Anyway, that's an interesting discussion. :)

Answer (score 1):

To go from one `StringBuilder` to another containing a segment of the original, you could use:

```
StringBuilder original = ...;
StringBuilder sub = new StringBuilder().append(original, offset, length);
```

This *could* have been provided as a method of `original`, but as things stand it isn't.

This aside, you should profile your code before engaging in micro-optimisations of this sort.